# HttpClient.GetStringAsync() "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Trying to scrape homepage of website https://genshin.gg

```cs
public class Scraper
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    
    public async Task<string> GetPage(string url)
    {
        return await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }

    public async Task GetCharacterList()
    {
        var html = await GetPage($"{Urls.Root}");
    }
}
```

And my response is as follows

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><meta name="title" content="Default Title" data-react-helmet="true"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><script type="text/javascript">window.nitroAds=window.nitroAds||{createAd:function(){window.nitroAds.queue.push(["createAd",arguments])},queue:[]}</script><script async src="https://s.nitropay.com/ads-536.js"></script><script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-61167242-9"></script><script>function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],gtag("js",new Date),gtag("config","UA-61167242-9")</script><link href="/static/css/2.861bd522.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.3d1b3cc3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,i,l=r[0],a=r[1],f=r[2],p=0,s=[];p<l.length;p++)i=l[p],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i)&&o[i]&&s.push(o[i][0]),o[i]=0;for(n in a)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,n)&&(e[n]=a[n]);for(c&&c(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,f||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,l=1;l<t.length;l++){var a=t[l];0!==o[a]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=i(i.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function i(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,i),t.l=!0,t.exports}i.m=e,i.c=n,i.d=function(e,r,t){i.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},i.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},i.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=i(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(i.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)i.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},i.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return i.d(r,"a",r),r},i.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},i.p="/";var l=this["webpackJsonpgenshin-react"]=this["webpackJsonpgenshin-react"]||[],a=l.push.bind(l);l.push=r,l=l.slice();for(var f=0;f<l.length;f++)r(l[f]);var c=a;t()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.0828fb28.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.c243af83.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

The notable part is `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>`

I am using JetBrains Rider 2020.2 and its default browser is set to MS Edge, but I have JS enabled and I'm not sure if the browser is even related.

Any idea how to workaround this? I have seen many similar problems in SO but they are JS and don't provide helpful answers for me, so please don't close this as duplicate.

Comment: Modern webpages are not just html. They are a combination of scripts and loadable dynamic content. For what ever reason, this page expects you to either run a script or at least load the code for it. The easiest approach from here is use a tool that can render a page including such content.

Comment: @TheGeneral how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You might be better off using browser automation (Selenium, Puppeteer Sharp, etc.)

Comment: Could you include in your question the `GetPage` method?